# Understanding the alternate method for evaluating the number of ways for below question

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Number of positive ($0$ excluded) integral solutions which contains only $1,2,3$ as variable values to the equation $a_1 +a_2 + a_3 + \ldots + a_6 = 12$ are?

> My method was this: It's equivalent to finding coefficient of $x^{12}$ in expansion of $(x+x^2 +x^3)^6$, from that I managed to attain the value as $141$, but I saw a method which I don't get how they managed to do it.  They wrote this :  $${11 \choose 2} - 5{8 \choose 2} + 15{5 \choose 2} - 15{2 \choose 2} = 141$$ cases. It might be related to PIE but I am not getting how.  Can anyone elaborate how they are doing it?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion over whether any (*and thus how many*) of the numbers exceeded the upper limit?  I would have expected $-6$ there, not $-5$.  That looks like a typo... that would lead to the expression $\binom{11}{5} - \binom{6}{1}\binom{8}{5}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{5}\color{grey}{-0+0-0+0}=141$

Comment: It is worth noting that the expression you have written here... $\binom{11}{2}-5\binom{8}{2}+15\binom{5}{2}-15\binom{2}{2}$ is equal to only $50$ which is incorrect.  Either the expression is the answer to a different question, or has serious errors or typos.

Comment: Have you been taught what is popularly known as *stars and bars* ?

Comment: Note that $$(x+x^2+x^3)^6=x^6(1+x+x^2)^6 =x^6\frac{(1-x^3)^6}{(1-x)^6}$$ 
The problem is equivalent to  finding the coefficients of $x^6$ in the expansion of $\frac{(1-x^3)^6}{(1-x)^6}$. The given answer seems to  come from using the generating  function of $\frac {1}{(1-x)^6}$ and the binomial expansion of $(1-x^3)^6$to find the coefficient of $x^6$.

Comment: Yeah i understand that one , that was what i did @LiKwokKeung

Comment: Understood @JMoravitz thanks

Comment: Let there is $n$ 1s ($n=0,1,2,3$), then there is $n$ 3s, and $6-2n$ 2s. Then there is exactly ${6 \choose n} \cdot {6-n \choose n}=\frac{6!}{n!^2 (6-2n)!}$ ways for sum. Then answer is $\sum_{n=0}^3 \frac{6!}{n!^2 (6-2n)!} = 141$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JMoravitz indicated in the comments, the correct expression should be
$$\binom{11}{5} - \binom{6}{1}\binom{8}{5} + \binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{5}$$

A particular solution of the equation
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 = 12 \tag{1}$$
corresponds to placing $6 - 1 = 5$ addition signs in the $12 - 1 = 11$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $12$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 3, x_4 = 4, x_5 = x_6 = 1$.  The number of such solutions is
$$\binom{12 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{11}{5}$$
since we must select which five of the eleven spaces between successive ones in which to place an addition sign.

The number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the positive integers is
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$
since a solution corresponds to placing $k - 1$ addition signs in the $n - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $n$ ones.

We wish to exclude solutions in which at least one of the variables exceeds $3$.  There can be at most two such variables since $3 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 1 = 15 > 12$.

*One variable exceeds* $3$:  There are six choices for the variable which exceeds $3$.  Suppose it is $a_1$.  Then $a_1 \geq 4$, so $a_1' = a_1 - 3$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $a_1' + 3$ for $a_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
a_1' + 3 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 & = 12\\
a_1' + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 & = 9 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers with $\binom{9 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{8}{5}$ solutions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{6}{1}\binom{8}{5}$$
cases in which a variable exceeds $3$.

However, if we subtract this amount from the total, we will have subtracted too much.  That is because we have subtracted cases in which two variables each exceed $3$ twice, once for each variable we could designate as the one that exceeds $3$.  We only want to subtract those cases once, so we must add them to the total.

*Two variables each exceed* $3$:  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select the two variables which exceed $3$.  Suppose they are $a_1$ and $a_2$.  Then $a_1' = a_1 - 3$ and $a_2' = a_2 - 3$ are positive integers.  Substituting $a_1' + 3$ for $a_1$ and $a_2' + 3$ for $a_2$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
a_1' + 3 + a_2' + 3 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 & = 12\\
a_1' + a_2' + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 & = 6 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the positive integers with one solution.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{5}$$
cases in which two variables exceed $3$.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of solutions of equation 1 in which no variable exceeds $3$ is
$$\binom{11}{5} - \binom{6}{1}\binom{8}{5} + \binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{5}$$

Comment: In equation 2 we still can have a_2 ,a_3 to be 4 isnt ? So that means it will have (a_1 ,a_2) or (a_1,a_3) both to be exceeding 3 isnt ? But the case was we want only one of them has 3 to be exceed isnt ?

Comment: In equation 2, I assumed $a_1$ was the variable that exceeded $3$.  It is possible for one of the other variables to also exceed $3$, which is why I had to add those cases back.  However, it is not possible for $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ to all exceed $3$ since the smallest total we could then get would be $4 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 15 > 12$.

Comment: Understood thanks a lot :)